# RxJava - Mapping an Observable is not returning all emissions

Tags: rx-java

I have an array of objects (with 36 objects) and I'm creating an observable from it. Then I try to map it to another type ... However, only one emission occurs.
Can anyone help me here:

```
    TypeA[] array = new TypeA[];
    // filling array
         return Observable.from(array)
                        .concatMap(new Func1<TypeA, Observable<? extends TypeB>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<? extends TypeB> call(TypeA typeA) {
                                return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<TypeB>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Subscriber<? super TypeB> subscriber) {                        
                                        Log.d("Here");

                                        subscriber.onNext(new TypeB());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

When I subscribe on it it only prints "Here" once, despite the array of objects have size of 36. What am I seeing wrong here?

Comment: Do your damdest to avoid calling `Observable.create` because you have to consider backpressure requirements. Use Observable.from(array).concatMap(typeA -> Observable.just(new TypeB()).doOnSubscribe(()-> Log.d("here")));

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `concatMap`, the operator will only consider the second array element when your inner stream terminates.

In your case it never terminates because you don't call `subscriber.onComplete();` after `onNext`.

Note that depending how close your code is from this sample, you'd better write:

```
Observable.from(array).map(ta -> new TypeB());
```

or (if the concatMap is really required):

```
Observable.from(array).concatMap(ta -> Observable.just(new TypeB()));
```

Comment: There can't be a `return` method in Java because it's a keyword; we named it `just` instead.